# how to auto fill like @gmail.com in html form

Tags: html, css

i have a form where every email is registered with @scoops.com but every time i have to enter @scoops.com i want that user just enter email name and @scoops.com auto fill and it will also show at the end of input field ? here it is my code

```
<div class="form-group" autocomplete="off">
        <label>Email <span style="opacity: 0.5; font-style: italic;">(Required)</span></label>
        <input autocomplete="nope" type="text" name="email" id="email"  class="form-control input-lg" 
        placeholder="Enter Email" name="name" required=""/>
        <span id="error_email"></span>
        @if($errors->has('email'))
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{ $errors->first('email') }}
        </div>
        @endif
      </div>
```

i want something like this

[image: i want something like this]

Comment: And what have you done already to achieve "_something like this_"? Since you're using Bootstrap, have you taken a look into "input groups"?

Comment: no i tried to find solution on google but nothing found im not experienced in html css

Comment: Have a look at the [input groups](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/) which @kerbholz referred to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use Bootstrap: Try to wrap your mail input into an Inputgroup.
And then append the mail ending(by grouping your inputs). Also im not sure if 'autocomplete="nope"' is a state for this attribute. You should consider "off" if nope means no.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="email" id="email"  class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter Email" name="name" required=""/>
     <div class="input-group-append">
         <span class="input-group-text">@scoops.com</span>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1 more question how i can concatinate @scoops.com with user name means user just enter like rablin92 and on submit scoops.com auto attached?

Comment: This depends when you want it. I dont know you code, you could do it in your JS/(jquery)/even after your ajax call if you use it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what´s been said above, you can do something like the code below to submit the user-typed value appended with whatever text you want:

```
<input id="myInput">
<button onclick="submit(document.getElementById('myInput').value)"></button>

<script>
  function submit(inputValue) {
    const email = inputValue + "@scoops.com"
    // insert here the code (like a POST request) to send the 'email' constant to wherever you want
  }
</script>
```